What is a homotopy pushout? Non-categorical terms please
I was wondering what a homotopy pushout is? (Please avoid using things like colimits, limits and other technical categorical terms).
Is it defined as follows:
Let $A,B,C$ be topological spaces with maps $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:A\rightarrow C$ then it is the "adjunction" space $B\cup_{A}C$? If so why is it called homotopy pushout?

It is not necessarily the adjunction space because the pushout is not homotopy invariant; e.g., the pushouts of $\ast \leftarrow S^1 \rightarrow \ast$ and $D^2 \leftarrow S^1 \rightarrow D^2$ are $\ast$ and $S^2$, respectively. Also, notions like limits and colimits are fundamental, not "technical categorical terms," and you should probably learn about them if you're interested in homotopy theory.

The simplest explanation I can think of is that the homotopy pushout is a way to remedy the fact that the pushout of a span $B \leftarrow A \to C$ is not homotopy invariant: If you replace $A$, $B$ and $C$ with homotopy equivalent spaces (and the morphisms accordingly), the pushout of this new span need not be homotopy equivalent to the pushout of the old span. This is clearly undesirable from a homotopy theoretic point of view, and the homotopy pushout is a way to avoid this.

Reversing the direction of your "is", suspensions are homotopy pushouts.

@WhileIAm But notions like limits and colimits are categorial terms. I'd rather say that you shouldn't be afraid of category theory; it's a tool that allows you to be both precise and general by abstracting away from concrete constructions and properties you already know. Certainly modern homotopy theory is completely unthinkable without it. :)

@BenSteffan I agree, but I am confused with the formal definition of what it is. If it's okay with you could perhaps elaborate in an answer on the formal definition?

Some more context would help: why do you want to know what a homotopy pushout is? (Especially, why are you looking at homotopy pushouts if you don't want to talk about category theory???)

@QiaochuYuan I just don't want to deal with the abstraction - I understand category theory is useful and but I think this can be explained without getting into too much technical jargon

Let me try to give an elementary answer.
Let $A \overset{f}{\leftarrow} B \overset{g}{\rightarrow} C$ be a span of topological spaces, which is simply to say that $A, B$ and $C$ are topological spaces and that $f$ and $g$ are continuous maps. The pushout of this span is the space $A \sqcup_B C := A \sqcup C / {{\sim}}$ where $\sim$ is generated by $f(b) \sim g(b)$ for all $b \in B$. This space sits in an commutative square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    B @>f>> A \\
    @VgVV @VV\iota_A V\\
    C @>>\iota_C > A \sqcup_B C
\end{CD}
where $\iota_A$ and $\iota_C$ are the inclusions, with the property that for any other commutative square
\begin{CD}
    B @>f>> A \\
    @VgVV @VVV\\
    C @>>> D
\end{CD}
there exists a unique map $A \sqcup_B C \to D$ making the "union" of these diagrams commute. Of course, changing $A \sqcup_B C$ out for any space homeomorphic to it doesn't change this property; if you're doing topology this is barely worth mentioning since by definition two homeomorphic spaces are topologically indistinguishable. In fact, rather than declaring that $A \sqcup_B C$ be the pushout of the given span, it turns out that we could have used its universal property as the defining feature ("a pushout of this span is a choice of space $P$ together with maps $A \to P$, $C \to P$ making the obvious square commute such that for any other commutative square [...]"): One rather direct consequence of this universal property is, after all, that any two such pushout candidates $P$ and $P'$ are homeomorphic (if this is unfamiliar, you should prove it as an exercise), so they're all homeomorphic to $A \sqcup_B C$.
We can thus draw two conclusions: (a) we can think of the pushout as being given by a universal property, and of $A \sqcup_B C$ as a model for this particular pushout, and (b) pushouts are invariant under homeomorphisms.
That's all very nice, but let's assume we're not here to do point-set topology but algebraic topology. As algebraic topologists, all our gadgets are not just topological invariants, i.e. they do not only respect homeomorphisms, but homotopy invariants: They turn homotopy equivalences into isomorphisms.
...but we're still interested in studying spaces and constructions on spaces, of which the pushout is a rather fundamental one (think about all the gluing we do). Thus, it's a natural question to ask whether the pushout is homotopy invariant: Given a morphism of spans $(A' \overset{f'}\leftarrow B' \overset{g'}\rightarrow C') \to (A \overset{f}\leftarrow B \overset{g}\rightarrow C)$, i.e. a commutative diagram
\begin{CD}
    A' @<f'<< B' @>g'>> C' \\
    @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
    A @<<f< B @>>g> C
\end{CD}
there is an induced map $\rho$ from $P'$, the pushout of the upper span, to $P$, that of the lower span (think about why). If all the vertical maps are homotopy equivalences, then is $\rho$ an equivalence, too?
Unfortunately (well, your mileage may vary) the answer is no:
Borrowing While I Am's example, the morphism of spans
\begin{CD}
    D^2 @<\iota<< S^1 @>\iota>> D^2 \\
    @VVV @V\mathrm{id}_{S^1}VV @VVV \\
    * @<<< S^1 @>>> *
\end{CD}
where $\iota$ is the inclusion of the boundary induces a map from $S^2$, the pushout of the upper span, to the pushout of the lower span which is simply a point, and this map can obviously not be a homotopy equivalence even though the displayed map of spans is.
This is an issue: For instance, I might hope that I can compute $\pi_*$, or $H_*$, or any homotopy invariant, really, of a pushout in terms of the span it is a pushout of, but if changing the span up to homotopy can drastically change the pushout (a point is maximally uninteresting whereas $S^2$ is a very interesting space, speaking from the point of view of homotopy theory), then there's probably only so much I can gather.
Coming at it from another angle, when doing homotopy theory we really would like to do as other mathematicians do: If you're doing linear algebra, then two (finite-dimensional) vector spaces are (more or less) the same when there exists a linear isomorphism between them, and all the constructions you do respect this notion of "sameness" (you can switch out one vector space for an isomorphic one in a direct sum or tensor product, for instance, without changing the isomorphism type of the construction as a whole). If you do point-set topology, two spaces are the same if they are homeomorphic, and you can swap them out for each other as you desire. If you're doing homotopy theory, thus, you want to consider homotopy equivalent spaces as "the same," and have your constructions be invariant with respect to this notion of sameness. But pushouts are certainly constructions we care about (for instance, all those CW-complexes we use are defined using pushouts), but as we've just shown they most certainly do not respect homotopy equivalences!¹
Thus, we need a replacement, and this is precisely the notion of homotopy pushout. I'll follow the outline above and introduce a model first: Given a span $A \overset{f}{\leftarrow} B \overset{g}{\rightarrow} C$ as before, let
$$
    M(f, g) := A \sqcup (B \times I) \sqcup C / {{\sim}}
$$
where $(b, 0) \sim f(b)$ and $(b, 1) \sim g(b)$ for all $b \in B$ be the double mapping cylinder of $f$ and $g$. It's much like $A \sqcup_B C$ except that instead of making the identifications directly, you instead take a cylinder of $B$ and make the identifications at its ends.
$M(f, g)$ sits in a homotopy commutative diagram
\begin{CD}
    B @>f>> A \\
    @VgVV @VV\iota_A V\\
    C @>>\iota_C> M(f, g)
\end{CD}
with $\iota_A$, $\iota_C$ the inclusions. The homotopy $H\colon \iota_C g \Rightarrow \iota_A f$ witnessing the commutativity of the square is simply given by $H_t(b) = (b, t)$. It should now be unsurprising that $M(f, g)$ has something resembling the universal property of the pushout "up to homotopy:" Given a homotopy commutative square
\begin{CD}
    B @>f'>> A \\
    @Vg'VV @VV\psi_A V\\
    C @>>\psi_C> D
\end{CD}
and a homotopy $G\colon \psi_C g' \Rightarrow \psi_A f'$ witnessing its commutativity, there's a map $\theta\colon M(f, g) \to D$ making the resulting diagram commute, again up to homotopy; concretely, this map is given by
$$
\begin{align}
    \theta(a) &= \psi_A \quad\text{if } a \in A \\
    \theta(c) &= \psi_C \quad\text{if } c \in C \\
    \theta(b, t) &= G(b, t) \quad \text{if } (b, t) \in B \times \operatorname{int} I
\end{align}
$$
I'll leave checking the details to you. The only thing to verify then is that we've avoided the issue of homotopy equivalent spans producing inequivalent pushouts. I am told this is possible to do directly, but for the sake of brevity (ha) I'll resort to a homotopy theoretic argument: Let $U \subset M(f, g)$ be the open set containing $A$ and $B \times [0, 3/4)$ and similarly $V \subset M(f, g)$ that containing $C$ and $B \times (1/4, 1]$. Denoting the analogous cover of $M(f', g')$ for $f'$, $g'$ the structure maps of a homotopy equivalent span as before by $U'$ and $V'$, the induced maps $U \to U'$, $V \to V'$ and $U \cap V \to U' \cap V'$ are all homotopy equivalences (since $U$ deformation retracts onto $A$, $V$ onto $C$, and $U \cap V$ onto $B$), so applying van Kampen's theorem, considering the Mayer-Vietories sequence and using their naturality, we see that the comparison map induces isomorphisms on $\pi_1$ and on all homology groups with local coefficients, so by a version of Whiteheads theorem the map is a (weak) equivalence.
Unfortunately, as far as I'm aware, there's no way to characterize the homotopy pushout in terms of universal properties on this basic level (if I'm wrong then hopefully someone will correct me in the comments). In particular, you should note that there's no uniqueness requirement on (homotopy classes of) maps out of the homotopy colimit (for reasons related to the issues described in ¹). The best we can do, since naturally the notion should be homotopy invariant, is to say that a homotopy pushout is a something homotopy equivalent to $M(f, g)$.
To sum up, a homotopy pushout is a way to take a span and replace its ordinary pushout by something that behaves like a "homotopy-invariant pushout:" It is defined up to homotopy equivalence, unaffected by replacing spans up to homotopy, and satisfies an reasonable analogue of the universal property of the pushout up to homotopy.

Loose ends & bits:
I allowed myself to simplify the discussion of spans a little bit by requiring morphisms of spans to commute on the nose, not up to homotopy. The latter is arguably more correct but leads to even more words and notation. I also omitted a discussion of maps from the homotopy to the ordinary pushout.
One can replace "homotopy equivalence" by "weak homotopy equivalence" everywhere above and everything should still work out just fine.
The construction presented above is sort-of ad-hoc: I'm not sure how far one can carry it for other homotopy colimits, but the discussion of general homotopy co/limits mostly uses different techniques. On that note, as evidenced by the comments under the original question, the theory of homotopy co/limits is deep and quite complicated: For a start, they belong to the realm of model categories, i.e. categories equipped with additional structure that allows us to do homotopy theory inside of them, and it takes a lot of work to derive a general, robust definition. I recommend this paper by Daniel Dugger if you're interested.
Linking this up with what you know, one can show that if $f$ or $g$ are cofibrations, then the ordinary pushout is already a homotopy pushout (as in, it is homotopy equivalent to $M(f, g)$). This reconciles many ordinary pushouts, for instance those appearing in the definition of CW-complexes, with the homotopy pushout. It also gives another construction of the latter: Simply replace $f$ or $g$ with a cofibration and take the ordinary pushout.
Final point: Another benefit of the homotopy pushout (and homotopy co/limits) in general is that their invariants (homology and cohomology, at least) are relatively easily computable from their spans; I made use of this to show homotopy invariance.

¹If you know about categories, then you'll undoubtedly recognize that I'm talking about a category for homotopy theory. At first glance, there's an obvious candidate: Just take the (naive) homotopy category $\mathrm{hTop}$ with the same objects as $\mathrm{Top}$ and morphisms given by homotopy classes of morphisms in $\mathrm{Top}$; then constructions in $\mathrm{hTop}$ are by definition homotopy invariant! Unfortunately, as you may have guess from the epithet "naive," this doesn't work out very well: $\mathrm{hTop}$ does not admit limits or colimits in general (in particular, it does not have all pushouts).

Would +2 if I could. Incredible answer

@Ben Steffan This is amazing. Very clear. Thank you Ben, very much.
